# Landing Currency for Type Rating Airplanes

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, currency

When discussing landing currency, we need three takeoffs and landings within the preceding 90 days in the same category, class, and type of aircraft to be flown. Type meaning type rating and not just 172 vs PA28. I understand if you do your landings in a Piper Seminole (AMEL) you're not current in a 737. However, if you're type rated in the 737 and do your 3 landings in the 737, does that also count for your currency for the Piper Seminole. Like would the currency for a plane with a type rating count for the plane without a type rating given they're the same category and class? It feels silly to ask but just want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If you are landing current a B737, you will also be landing current in a non-type rating AMEL aircraft as well.